# xp_copy_file coughing on parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Just upgraded to SQL Server 2019, and trying out `xp_copy_file`, which looks straight-forward, but is coughing up `'Invalid parameter'` when I try it.

---

**For Example:**

```
exec master.sys.xp_copy_file  
'C:\installs\xptest.txt', 
'C:\installs\xptest2.txt'
```

I've tried it on multiple servers, file locations, file names, with the same result. Obviously, I'm doing something simple wrong, but I cant see it.

FYI, I'm aware of other ways to do this; this is simply a new feature in 2019 so I thought I'd try it out to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
DECLARE @targetDirectory nvarchar(4000) = N'C:\installs\xptest.txt'
DECLARE @destinationDirectory nvarchar(4000) = N'C:\installs\xptest2.txt'

exec master.sys.xp_copy_file @targetDirectory, @destinationDirectory
```

I have seen this approach work in similar situations with commands such as `xp_create_subdir`.

Comment: THanks Patrick, but sadly, that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

The `sys.sp_MSreplcopyscriptfile` references the `sys.xp_copy_files` Extended Stored Procedure.  Note, the name is plural, as in *files* not *file*.

This is the definition of the proc from SQL Server version 15.0.4249.2

```
--
-- Name: sp_MSreplcopyscriptfile
--
-- Descriptions: 
--
-- Parameters: as defined in create statement
--
-- Returns: 0 - success
--          1 - Otherwise
--
-- Security: Public procedure invoked via RPC. db_owner check
--
-- Requires Certificate signature for catalog access
--
CREATE PROCEDURE sys.sp_MSreplcopyscriptfile
(
    @directory nvarchar(4000),
    @scriptfile nvarchar(4000) 
)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @retcode int
    
    --
    -- security check
    -- only sysadmin can execute this
    --
    if (isnull(is_srvrolemember('sysadmin'),0) = 0) 
    begin
        raiserror(14260, 16, -1)
        return (1)
    end
    
    begin try
        exec @retcode = xp_create_subdir @directory
    end try
    begin catch
        set @retcode = 1
    end catch
    if(@retcode <> 0)
    begin
        raiserror(21330, 16, -1, @directory)
        return (1)
    end

    begin try
        exec @retcode = xp_copy_files @scriptfile, @directory
    end try
    begin catch
        set @retcode = 1
    end catch
    if(@retcode <> 0)
    begin 
        raiserror(21331, 16, -1, @directory)
        return (1)
    end

    return (0)
end
```

From the definition of the above stored procedure, we can infer that `xp_copy_files` requires two parameters of type `nvarchar(4000)`, and that the 1st parameter is the name of the source file, and the 2nd parameter is the target directory for the copy operation.

And in fact, this works:

```
DECLARE @source_file nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @destination_folder nvarchar(4000);

SET @source_file = N'C:\source\folder\my_file.txt'; --file name
SET @destination_folder = N'C:\destination\folder'; --name of existing folder only

EXEC sys.xp_copy_files @source_file, @destination_folder;
```

The non-plural form of the XP, `sys.xp_copy_file` then surely allows you to copy a single file, and in fact it does just that:

```
DECLARE @source_file nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @destination_file nvarchar(4000);


SET @source_file = N'C:\source\folder\my_file.txt'; --existing source file name
SET @destination_file = N'C:\destination\folder\my_file.txt';  --target file name

EXEC sys.xp_copy_file @source_file, @destination_file;
```

I've tested both Extended Stored Procedures using the code above and have verified that they both work.  Note that the destination folder must previously exist for both scenarios.  If the destination folder does not exist, `sys.xp_copy_files` returns the following error:

> Msg 22052, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
> xp_copy_files() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

If you attempt to use `sys.xp_copy_file` and specify only the target directory name for the 2nd parameter (i.e. *not* a file name, where the target directory already exists), you get the following error:

> Msg 22052, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
> xp_copy_file() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.'